# Adding Html button and Onclick using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
 function showDescription(td)
{
     var desc = $(td).children("input:first").val(); 
     var Button = $('<input type="button" value="Accept" onClick=validateUserInput(' + desc + '); style="float:right;"/>');
     var dlg = $("#div");
     dlg.append(Button);
}
```

desc is in format of 49.595,-126.592 49.620,-126.602 49.642,-126.606

When I inspect the view source I see it in format.

```
<input type="button" style="float: right;" 49.620,-126.602);=""  49.642,-126.606=""  onclick="validateUserInput(49.595,-126.592" value="something">
```

How do I indent desc so that its read as one single string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have it passed to the function as a single string surround your onclick method in single quotes and the value in double quotes (single always precedes double):

```
var Button = $('<input type="button" 
                         value="Accept" 
                         onClick=\'validateUserInput("' + desc + '")\';
                         style="float:right;"/>');
```

And if you want to parse them later:

```
function validateUserInput(string desc)
{
    var descVals = desc.split(',');

    // descVals[0] = "49.595"
    // descVals[1] = "-126.592 49.620"
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the onClick attribute, otherwise it is treating each set of numbers as an attribute, not a value.  Your button code should look like this:

```
var Button = $('<input type="button" value="Accept" onClick="validateUserInput(' + desc + ');" style="float:right;"/>');
```